# how can create automatically a work item when i checkin project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, c#-3.0, tfsbuild

i want to create a work item (For example a task and assign to administrator) automatically when i checkin project in tfs 2010.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a CI to build each check-in and customize build process to create a task workitem and assign it to administrator.

Comment: thanks jehan33 
can you explain your idea a few more please? , i don't know how to configure it. 
can i implement this problem with checkin policy?
thanks fore your help...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up WCF Service endpoint and subscribe to various TFS events.
Check Answer 5 of [this](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/consume-events-tfs-3530.aspx), for an example of a Checkin-Notification.
Once you 're successful on that, check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsgeneral/thread/1ff5415e-0ef2-4c65-b0b7-a109187adf51) for an intro on how to generate any work item using the TFS-SDK.